# Using "deposit money" in a sentence

Tags: tense

> I am deposited money 100rs. in your account.

Is this sentence right or wrong?

Answer (score 7):

*I am* would always have to be speaking in the present.

> I am depositing 100rs. in your account.

That is the speaker telling you what they are doing, right now.  It's the kind of thing someone might say over the phone as they make the transaction.

If you are talking about something that happened in the past, the "I am" needs to go.  Instead you would change the tense of the verb.

> I have deposited 100rs. in your account.

But "have" still puts the context a bit in close to the present.  It's like you are talking about something you have just done recently.  Take away the "have", you could be talking about any point in time... even a long time ago.

> "How many rupees did you put in my account four years ago?"
>
> "I deposited 100rs. in your account."

You would not say "I have deposited" in that case.

Comment: One additional case, to be used if the transaction has not been performed yet: In that case, one could say, _I will deposit 100rs. into your account_, or, _I will be depositing 100rs. into your account._ (Also worth noting, I think: either _in_ or _into_ could be used as a preposition in these sentences.)

Comment: Note that we don't say "money" with a specific amount, i.e. we don't say "money 100rs.", just "100rs.". I presume because it would be redundant: as opposed to 100 rupees of rain? We use the word "money" when not giving the specific amount. Like, "How much money did you deposit in my account?" "Bob worries about money too much", etc.

Comment: "I am would always have to be speaking in the present." are you sure? I would say that in passive case you should use **I am** with the 3rd form of verb. For example: I'm expressed by... And there are a lot of more examples.